# What does "index sets are filtered" mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I am reading a book and it stated "All index sets will be assumed to be filtered". I was wondering if someone could explain what this meant. I did a quick search on the web but I couldn't figure out exactly what the author meant. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are almost certainly talking about a [directed set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_set). This is a poset $(I, \leq)$ with the additional property that for each $x, y \in I$ there is a $z \in I$ such that $x \leq z$ and $y \leq z$. That is, each pair of elements has an upper bound.

Comment: That would be idealized, being upward directed.  To be filtered, it would be downward directed.  My guess is that either the set is a filter or the indexes are a filter.

Comment: I'm almost certain I've read "filtered" for upwards directed, and the linked Wikipedia article seems to agree with me. Upwards directed is also a property that makes sense for indexing sets.

Comment: The index set of nets by convention, are up directed.